# How to make a list with set(i, ele), add(), remove() methods in O(1)?

Tags: list, data-structures

As title, I want to make a list with `set(i, ele)`, `add(ele) (at front or at the end)`, `remove(ele) (at font or at the end)` in O(1).
It is easy to make add() and remove() operations in O(1) if we use a linked list. But with a linked list, we cannot access i-th element in O(1).

According to the comments, I should specify `add or remove` methods only work at front or at the end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the cost of retrieving (reading) an element is not specified, is it? Then, creating a log of all set, add, remove operations in a linked list and following the list from the beginning for reading an element should work.

Comment: `remove()` isn't O(1) in a linked list, you have to search the list for the element. Unless it's a doubly-linked list.

Comment: @Barmar Even with a doubly-linked list, you still have to search for the element. Doubly-linked only means that you can iterate forward and backward as well.

Comment: @Fareanor I assumed `ele` is the list node, not the value. So you just have to do `ele.prev.next = ele.next; ele.next.prev = ele.prev;` (with appropriate checks for NULL)

Comment: @Barmar Oh right, but the node implementation should not be accessible for the user, if you take a look at how the standard library works, you never use nodes :)

Comment: What `set(i, ele)` is doing? Is it *inserting* the element into position `i`?

Comment: @Fareanor he's designing something new, it doesn't have to follow the model of the STL.

Comment: Why is this tagged with three different languages?

Comment: The long and short of this is you can't.  You are always going to have a trade off somewhere.  In order to guarantee O(1) insertion and removal, you can't have random access, so you can't have an O(1) set.  With vector, it's the other way around.  FWIW, often times `vector` is faster than `list`, because modern CPU's really like array like structures: https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html

Comment: Seems like you could do this with a python dictionary.  Of course you would not be able to insert new nodes in the middle, but you didn't ask for that, so -- problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *hash table* : insert, delete and search is all O(1) in average and O(n) in worst case

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Thanks for answering. :)

Answer (score -1):

In C++ you can use the Vector container to insert, add, remove:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_vector(vector<int> v) {
    for (auto & n : v)
            cout << n << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}

int main(void) {
    vector<int> v = {3,5,6,7};

    print_vector(v);
    v.push_back(8); // add at end of vector
    print_vector(v);

    if (v.size()) // protection
        v.pop_back(); // remove at end of vector
    print_vector(v);

    int i = 3;
    if (v.size <= i) // protection
        v.insert(v.begin() + i, 42); // insert 42 at index i
    print_vector(v);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
3 5 6 7 
3 5 6 7 8 
3 5 6 7 
3 5 6 42 7
```

Comment: removing an element in the middle from a vector is not `O(1)`

Comment: his question lacks focus and will be closed soon anyways, just trying to be helpful and not much time ;) I think he wants to remove at end of vector, which is O(1) with pop_back()

Comment: slightly misleaing, because OP asks for `O(1)` erase and your code does erase in `O(1)` but in general it isnt `O(1)`

Comment: It is not possible in O(1)

Comment: it is with a different container, not with `std::vector`

Comment: yes but then the others will not be O(1), right. You cannot have the milk, the butter, the smile of the milkmaid and the stocks of the milk factory at the same time ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your code gives me a hint, I need to specify that `add()` and `remove()` methods only work at font or at the end.

Comment: Upvote or select as answer if it was helpful ;)